# Spring MVC Annotations with Global Context context:component-scan?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I have a spring dispatcher servlet with servlet-name "spring-mvc".  The spring-mvc-servlet.xml appears as follows:

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" 
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>

<bean 
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping"/>

<bean 
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter"/>
```

In a file in WEB-INF/annotation-context.xml I have the annotation scanner defined.  All of my annotated classes are loaded and other spring beans are able to load them ok.

However, the path mappings do not work from spring-mvc.  If I copy the context-scanner to spring-mvc-servlet.xml, then they work.

Is it possible for spring-mvc-servlet.xml to reference beans defined at the global spring level?

Comment: there's no such thing as "global spring level". What does this `WEB-INF/annotation-context.xml` file do, and what refers to it?

Comment: global spring level == application context (as opposed to a nested context in which a dispatcher servlet is defined)

Answer (score 2):

You can [load your contexts hierarchically](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/mvc.html#mvc-servlet) so that context described in `annotation-context.xml` becomes a parent of your Spring MVC context. The latter will then be able to access all the beans defines in the former.

[Spring documenation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#context-create) describes several ways to do it. For example, in your `web.xml`:

```
// load parent context
<context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/annotation-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

// load Spring MVC context
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>spring-mvc</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what I'm doing.  Controller's in the parent context are not seen by spring mvc in spring-mvc servlet's context.  They can be called manually however, just that dispatcherservlet doesn't see them or their path mappings.