# Spring @Controllers declared in the root application context

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Spring web applications have two context - the web context (child) and the root context (parent). If `@Controller` beans are defined in `dispatcher-servlet.xml` (the web context) everything is fine.

But if the controller beans are defined in the parent context (`applicationContext.xml`), then the controllers are not recognized - i.e. their mappings are not configured, so when you try to open `/foo/bar` defined in such controller, the path is not found.

The question is: how to make the controller mappings to be parsed no matter where the beans are defined.

P.S. I know I can move the declarations to the child context, but I don't want to do that for reasons beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757098/spring-mvc-annotations-with-global-context-contextcomponent-scan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping` has a [`detectHandlersInAncestorContexts`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.html#setDetectHandlersInAncestorContexts%28boolean%29) property that enables the desired behaviour.

Comment: well, I looked through all the classes in the hierarchy for such a property..but obviously I missed it. Thanks :)

Comment: now, the harder part is to use the DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping together with mvc:annotation-driven

Comment: @Bozho: I always use `BeanPostProcessor` to configure implicitly created beans in such cases.

Comment: @Bozho: A more interesting thing is that Spring 3.1's `RequestMappingHandlerMapping`, that is intended to be a drop-in replacement for `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping`, doesn't have such a property. Perhaps it should be reported.

Comment: That's a good idea. For bigger projects I "unfold" the annotation-driven tag (and remove it), but this would be an overhead here. I'll use a post-processor.