# spring mvc, no mapping found in DispatcherServlet, base-package with annotations

Tags: spring-mvc, annotations

i use Spring MVC with Spring 3.1

I place all the base-packages in the applicationContext.xml for the automatic component scanning. However, when im trying this, im getting the error:

```
No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/Test1/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'test'
```

I resolved the error above by adding the controller package in the test-servlet.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.george.controller" />
```

Why do i have to add explicitly the controller package in the test-servlet.xml, when i already add all my packages in the applicationContext.xml ?

**web.xml**

```
<context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml
        /WEB-INF/spring/dataContext.xml
</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
 <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<context:annotation-config />

<context:component-scan base-package="com.george.dao, com.george.service, com.george.controller" />

<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />   
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

**test-servlet.xml**

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />


<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

By default controllers should be declared in `test-servlet.xml`, not in `applicationContext.xml`.

In your case you can move `<context:component-scan>` for `controller` package to `test-servlet.xml`.

If package with controllers also contains other beans, you can use an approach described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4333390/service-are-constructed-twice). Also note that your package layout is considered to be an antipattern, it's recommended to package by feature rather than by layer.

Alternatively, you can override default behaviour [using `detectHandlersInAncestorContexts` property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7688843/spring-controllers-declared-in-the-root-application-context/7688937#7688937).